# onActivityResult() method doesn't get any result from Activity B?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

On Activity A sending intent with some string values:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.Changepin:{
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChangePwd.class);
            i.putExtra("plain1", plaintext);
            i.putExtra("cipher1", ciphertext);
            startActivityForResult(i,100);
            //startActivity(i);
            //finish();
        }
        break;
        default:{
            Log.e("","onOptionsItemSelected() Unknown menu event.");
        }
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==100){
            if(resultCode==10){

            String ciphertext1 = data.getStringExtra("changedcipher");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ciphertext1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("mainactivity", "" + ciphertext1);
    }
}
}
```

On Activity B calling setResult() with same result code as it matches with the result code onActivityResult() method on Activity A:

```
public void setNewPin(){
String ciphertext1=null;    Intent i = new Intent(ChangePwd.this,MainActivity.class);
try{
ciphertext1 = crypthelper.encrypt(plaintext);
}catch (Exception e) {
}
i.putExtra("changedcipher", ciphertext1);
setResult(10,i);
Toast.makeText(ChangePwd.this, ciphertext1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
finish();
}
```

Comment: my app crashes and when i debug my code than control doesn't come to onActivityResult() and code crashes.

Comment: post your logcat here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request codes you are using to denote call to Activity B are mis-matching here. The one you have put to start the Activity B is **2**

```
startActivityForResult(i,2);
```

and then in onActivityResult you check,

```
if(requestCode==100){ .. }
```

hence the issue. Change it to,

```
if(requestCode==2){ .. }
```

and it shall work. :)

Edit -

Change `Intent i = new Intent(ChangePwd.this,MainActivity.class);` to

```
Intent i = new Intent();
```

Comment: sry,i edit my problem..now request code and result code are same. but code crashes :(

Comment: only "showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection" like exception showing in logcat ,when i am debugging the code

Comment: Are you getting the Toast and Log inside your ActivityResult method? Can you post your Logcat?

Comment: problem is that i am not getting any toast on any of the activities.... som portion of logcat:::

Comment: 05-14 16:18:35.433: I/ActivityManager(273): START {cmp=com.rimus.Secret_Keeper/.ChangePwd (has extras) u=0} from pid 15382

05-14 16:18:57.883: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15382): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Comment: issue seems to be some where else. Can you post your entire code and logcat? Also try to put logs after every few steps and trace where the code goes wrong.

Comment: can Activity A get intent from Activity B and Activity C without setResult and onactivityResult method???

Comment: You will have to use Broadcast Receivers to notify Activity A. You tried having fragments instead of so many Activities. Just give it a thought.

Comment: Okk...although i don't have any idea about Broadcast Receivers usage but as u are saying then i'll give try...thanx

Comment: Your welcome. If you can explain what exactly you are trying to do I can get a clear vision? If you wanna tell ;)

Comment: Actually i have three activities A,B,C....i am sending intent with two strings from A to B and get result on A it comes perfectly but when i send intent with two strings From B to C than both string values reach on activity C but when i am trying to get result on B it fails.Although i debug my code step by step ,it works smoothly till it comes to setResult() method and finish(); activity C but on activity B onActivityresult() method doesn't call.when i saw the logcat only one exception like statement show "showStatusIcon on Inactive Inputconnection" i don't knw why it is happening....

Comment: can u please provide me any broadcast receiver sample code or any link  that can resolve my issue ?? if u wanna provide ;)

Comment: Fragments will be handy in your case(you will not require Broadcast Receiver then). Heres an awesome video for that - http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEgQtwIwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVyyGP_d0Ia8&ei=_WpzU7CpNpHkrAfe-YHgDw&usg=AFQjCNF5XeLcgw-DfTULky7BtIo9UQMM1A&bvm=bv.66699033,d.bmk&cad=rja  ------------- If you wish to continue with activities then see this http://www.androidpit.com/forum/550923/tutorial-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-broadcastreceiver

Comment: thanx for your help Atul O Holic :),but i don't want to complicate my task.i just want to recieve data back to my activity b from c through onActivityResult method which is not working properly.

Comment: yup sure. Hence I also mentioned the Broadcas Receiver thing. :)

Comment: ok....but this is not a big task thats why i am asking that is there any possibility within onactivityresult method??

Comment: onActivityResult works for single activity the direct Activity you call. So if you calling B from A, you can send results back to A from B ONLY.

Comment: One alternative could be saving the data from Activity C into a shared preference and then reading the same from Activity A. Shared Preferences are dynamic and take effect immediately. But this only takes data as Strings and in key value pair like Maps.

Comment: yes u r right....data coming from C to B should be saved in sharedpreferences on B so that i can use it .... hence on activity B i done this: @Override
SharedPreferences preferences = preferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("cipher1",ciphertext1);
editor.commit(); but problem is that onactivityresult method is not calling...:(

Comment: hey.. atul my issue is solved :) i use i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); for sending intent from Activity C to A and receive it...now i got the data on A and store it in shared preferences

Comment: congrats. :) nice to hear that. :) Do accept and upvote my answer if I helped you. :)